# how to query sqlalchemy by month name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried this

```
db_session.query(PaymentsMade).filter(func.strftime('%B', PaymentsMade.created_at) == "August").all()
```

but am getting this error

```
(ProgrammingError) function strftime(unknown, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 3: WHERE strftime('%B', paymentsmade.created_at) = 'August'
          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

and am saving the date `created_at = datetime.utcnow()`

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: **postgres** thanks for your responce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to call the PostgresSQL function [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html), not the Python `datetime` function `strftime`:

```
db_session.query(PaymentsMade) \
    .filter(func.to_char(PaymentsMade.created_at, "FMMonth") == "August")
```

Comment: perfect :) and how can i query on list of month ex "June, July, August"

Comment: @sunny - you should be able to change `) == "August"` to `).in_("June", "July", "August")` and have it work (but I'm not 100% sure about that).